# Widgets compiled from Xcode 15 are not available on iOS 16, while they are on iOS 15 and 17

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios15, ios16, ios17

Why widgets from iOS app are not available on the list on iOS 16, while on ios 17 and 15 are available?

This is how they are defined in widget bundle:

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ZeroWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        FirstWidgetBundle().body
        SecondWidgetBundle().body
        ThirdWidgetBundle().body
    }
}

struct FirstWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        WidgetLatestNews()
        WidgetLatestVideos()
        WidgetDailyText()
        WidgetOfficialSite()
    }
}

struct SecondWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        WidgetWatchtowerStudy()
        WidgetCurrentMonth()
        WidgetComing()
        if #available(iOS 16.1, *) {
            WidgetCurrentTime()
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        WidgetMinistry()
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            WidgetTimer()
        }
    }
}
```

it just works on 17 and 15, and doesn't work on 16. It started happening after 17 was released. It was working before. Where is the problem?

This is the screenshot where you can see the problem. Exactly **THE SAME** code was compiled on three devices using **Xcode 15.0 (15A240d)**

[image]

Feedback Assistant to Apple:

https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/13250847

Comment: If you've correctly installed the widget on all three simulators, then maybe worth filling a FeedbackAssistant to Apple for it?

Comment: Similar problem appeared 2 months ago and was asked on apple developer [forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734466?page=1#767932022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple. There is no explanation why Xcode compiles code excluded by `#available` (here `WidgetTimer`). But working solution for that is the following:

```
struct ThirdWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            return WidgetBundleBuilder.buildBlock(WidgetMinistry(), WidgetTimer())
        } else {
            return WidgetMinistry()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! This approach solved my problem